# Scheduled events disappear from events queue

Tags: plugin-development, events

I'm having an issue where events that I have scheduled work for a while then just stop. After looking at the event queue I see that the scheduled events are no longer in the queue.

If I deactivate then reactivate the plugin the schedule is back and works for a period of time.

I don't know if WordPress has something that removes events if they timeout or anything like that.

Here is my code:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'k2_section_featured_ads_setup');
function k2_section_featured_ads_setup() {
    wp_schedule_event('1395871200', 'minutely', 'k2_section_featured_ads_hook');
}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'k2_section_featured_ads_deactivation');
function k2_section_featured_ads_deactivation() {

    $featured_next = wp_next_scheduled('k2_section_featured_ads_hook');
    wp_unschedule_event($featured_next, 'k2_section_featured_ads_hook');
}

add_action('k2_section_featured_ads_hook', 'k2_section_featured_ads_check_time');

function k2_section_featured_ads_check_time() {
    // function here
}
```

Here is the filter for my extra cron schedules

```
function k2_cron_add_schedules( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['quarterday'] = array(
        'interval' => 14400,
        'display' => __('Once every 4 hours')
    );
    $schedules['minutely'] = array(
        'interval' => 60,
        'display' => __('Once every 1 minute')
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'k2_cron_add_schedules');
```

Comment: From the Wordpress docs: For some reason there seems to be a problem on some systems where the hook must not contain underscores or uppercase characters.

Comment: `'minutely'` is not a core-supplied interval. Though unlikely that this is the root of the problem, could you please supply the filter responsible for adding the interval and let us know where it resides?

Comment: @TomásCot: I cannot seem to find the passage that you are referencing - mind throwing us a link?

Comment: @boscho, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event#Parameters Read the `$hook` parameter.

Comment: @TomásCot totally looked over that - thanks! What a cryptic little note! I thought the source might elaborate on the issue further but no - you in fact quoted it verbatim.

Comment: @boscho, unfortunately the docs are full of those little tricks. It's hard not to overlook something.

Comment: @TomásCot I see that is says no underscores but every WP hook and others plugins I've see use underscores as well. Is there a legitimate reason for not using underscores?

Comment: @kel, I think it could be related with the `uksort` function using the `strnatcasecmp` comparison function, which can generate problems with strings with underscores

Comment: @TomásCot I have gone through my plugins and renamed the hooks to be all lowercase and have no underscores so they look like `k2_section_featured_ads_hook`. I am still having the issue. Any other ideas on what I can look at?

Comment: @kel, I would suggest rewriting everything from scratch.

Comment: @TomásCot I re-wrote the plugin, its super code optimized, there are no errors on anything but it still gets removed from WordPress' cron. Any other ideas? Could it be that it doesn't like running every minute? If that is the case, is there a safe zone?

Comment: Just chiming in to say me too. I have a custom scheduled event every minute. It runs fine for a couple weeks or so and then just disappears from the scheduled event list. Have to deactivate and reactivate the plugin and it's back.

Comment: @timeuser Just letting you know I still haven't found a fix for it. Just have to deactivate and reactivate :(

Comment: @kel The only other related discussion I found about this problem is http://www.thenewsletterplugin.com/forums/topic/disappearing-cron-event . It's mentioned in that thread a fatal error or out of memory can block WordPress from rescheduling a periodic cron. My suspicion is that the function is failing to successfully complete sometimes and so not being rescheduled. Perhaps traffic or other load such as backup running at the same time, or just failing for another reason. I run a couple rather complicated database queries. Whatever it is there is no easy way to troubleshoot I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for now is check every hour if it is running and if not reschedule it. I also remove this in deactivate etc.

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_restart_schedule_if_failed');

function my_restart_schedule_if_failed() {
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_scheduled_minute_job' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'one_minute', 'my_scheduled_minute_job' );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the workaround, but still most likely something is broken with some code if this happens

Answer (score 1):

After pouring all of my points into this question and trying a few suggested options it seems that WordPress can't handle one minute crons. I have changed it to 5 minutes and haven't had any issues since.

A few things that I tried over the course of weeks for testing purposes:

- Change the hook names to not include underscores [BUSTED]
- Rewrite the plugin. Was written procedurally originally and now its all OOP [BUSTED]
- Changed to 5 minute schedule [BUSTED]

**EDIT:** I originally marked the last as working but after all these months it was unscheduled again. I'm still not sure what's going on with all of this.

Answer (score 0):

This topic on [WP.ORG](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cron-jobs-dissapear-automatically/#post-14299272) would help.

Long story short - if there is issue or delay or break in the cron-job, it might get delisted by wp.